# Chrome's HTML 5 notifications in Windows 10 only allow one at a time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-10, html5-notifications

As of yesterday, Chrome's notifications by default go through the Action Center on Windows 10. This is great, except when you want to send multiple notifications, it looks like only one of them is visible.

If you want a persistant notification, that means that once that notification fires, you can't notify the user about anything until they dismiss the persistant notification!

Before the notifications were integrated with the action center, you could send multiple notifications at the same time, and they would funciton as expected.

Is there anyway to display multiple notifications with the default settings in Chrome after this update?

Comment: I made the same attempt two years ago, and even UWP apps can't display multiple notifications at the same time, so this is a design flaw in the native notifications of Win10, and I finally gave up.

Comment: @skeets Any luck with this? I am having the same requirement to show multiple notfications stacked on top of each other. ( Not the action center because action center is by default hidden and user has to click to view the action center contents).

Comment: @crystal_test No, Windows notifications still don't work very well with Chrome. I'm using JS to automatically close the notifications after a few seconds to increase my chances that the next notification will come through. Even then, Windows sometimes decides to be "smart" and minimize my notifications before I even see them (I think it's when I have a video playing... even if it's not even visible on the screen!)

Comment: Anyway, the only thing that consistently "works" is to add a custom sound that plays at the same time as the notification so that users are at least alerted if the notification fails to show.

Comment: @skeets Thank you for your response. You're right. when you are on "full screen" mode you will not see the notifications.

Comment: @skeets i submitted a chrome bug report. Please find the below link and star if possible. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334200

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to change the amount of notification per app, in the "Notifications & actions" settings page (this setting does not apply for notifications banner, unfortunately).

Just click on the Chrome icon in the applications list at the bottom of the page, and change the number of displayed notifications in the appropriate drop down.

Note you can simply tell Chrome to avoid using the Windows 10 action center by changing the value of the following flags ([chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags)):

- enable-native-notifications
- enable-message-center-new-style-notification

FYI, Windows just broke the handling of notifications' events (onclick, onclose...) at the time of writing these lines, while it works when using the notifications center of MacOs...

Comment: I'm mainly asking how it could be accomplished *without* changing default settings. (I want users of my site to be able to receive multiple notifications) Youtube seems to be accomplishing it somehow....